# Host IP address vs gateway IP address vs DHCP IP address

Tags: ip, ipv4, subnet, dhcp, ip-address

What is the difference between a host IP address, a gateway IP address, and a DHCP IP address when setting up networking devices?

For example, when configuring a virtual network adapter for my VM, I can configure an IP address and subnet mask for the adapter (i.e., the hardware itself?), such as `192.168.56.1/24`. I think this means the adapter will handle any requests to the IP address range of `192.168.56.0-192.168.56.255`. I am not sure what `192.168.56.1` refers to specifically; won't anything starting with `192.168.56` go to that adapter anyway?

On top of that, if I configure DHCP on my virtual network adapter, I again set an IP address and subnet mask but also a DHCP range. For example, an IP address/mask `192.168.56.100/24`, then a range of `192.168.56.101-192.168.56.105`. The DHCP range makes sense because it is the pool of addresses that the DHCP can assign, but what is the DHCP IP address for?

I am unclear where the gateway IP address (which I thought would be the address with the bits after the mask set to 0, traditionally) fits in here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can configure an IP address and subnet mask for the adapter (i.e.,
>   the hardware itself?), such as `192.168.56.1/24`. I think this means
>   the adapter will handle any requests to the IP address range of
>   `192.168.56.0`-`192.168.56.255`.

No, that is incorrect. An IPv4 address has two parts: the network and the host. Each device interface will have a host address on the particular network. An interface with the `192.168.56.1/24` address means that the network (the first 24 bits of the address) is `192.168.56` and the interface address (the last eight bits of the address) in that network is `1`. The interface only responds to that particular 32-bit address (excepting broadcasts and any multicasts for any groups to which it is subscribed).

> I am not sure what `192.168.56.1` refers to specifically; won't anything
>   starting with `192.168.56` go to that adapter anyway?

No, only packets destined to the full 32-bit IPv4 address will be used by that interface.

> On top of that, if I configure DHCP on my virtual network adapter, I
>   again set an IP address and subnet mask but also a DHCP range. For
>   example, an IP address/mask `192.168.56.100/24`, then a range of
>   `192.168.56.101`-`192.168.56.105`. The DHCP range makes sense because it is the pool of addresses that the DHCP can assign, but what is the
>   DHCP IP address for?

I do not really understand what you are doing with this. DHCP (Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol) is used to assign information to an interface, like IP addressing, a gateway address, DNS addresses, etc. If you are running a DHCP server on your host, then you would assign a range of addresses for a scope that other hosts use, and the DHCP server itself would require an IP address because it is a host on the network. If you are using DHCP to configure your interface, then you would not normally configure an IP address manually on the interface.

> I am unclear where the gateway IP address (which I thought would be
>   the address with the bits after the mask set to 0, traditionally) fits
>   in here.

No, that would be the network address, not a gateway address (except as in the IPv6 router anycast address). A gateway (usually a router) is a host on the network that know how to reach other networks. A gateway address is just another a host address, and it could be any host address on the network that gets assigned to the gateway.

---

You can learn more about IPv4 addressing in [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499).